# checkbox label width change for one thing

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

I have a checkbox which has a label, in one of my css the width of this label is set to 10cm
In my form I have multiple labels however for one of my labels I want it to span the whole page rather than 10cm. I don't want to override if possible as that would ruin the look of the rest of my form as there are other labels etc in there.
How can I do this for the one checkbox label?

Comment: Give it an ID and target it specifically in your CSS. Simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkboxes are within the same parent, you can use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`, alternatively you can target directly by `id` or using a good selector.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/rA2Xw/)

[**Use the `nth-child` selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>
> This can more clearly be described this way: the matching element is
>   the bth child of an element after all its children have been split
>   into groups of a elements each.
>
> The values a and b must both be integers, and the index of an
>   element's first child is 1.
>
> In other words, this class matches all children whose index fall in
>   the set { an + b; n = 0, 1, 2, ... }.
>
> Among other things, this allows selectors to match every other row in
>   a table.

[**OR `nth-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

> The :nth-of-type CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1
>   siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree,
>   for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>   See :nth-child for a more thorough description of the syntax of its
>   argument. This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector if you
>   want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag no matter where
>   it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags appear
>   before it.